# Как взять значение выбранной даты из календаря и сохранить ее в переменную в js

Tags: javascript

календарь

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label class="sr-only" for="dateBeg"</label>
    <input type="date" class="datepicker-here" id="dateBeg"   name="dateBeg"
     value="{{date('Y-m-d',($dateBeg))}}"
     onchange=" $('#all-member-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();"
     min="1870-01-01" max="{{date('Y-m-d',time())}}">
     </div>
```

событие:

```
    target = '';
    document.querySelector('.datepicker-here').addEventListener('change', (e) => { target= e.target.value; });
```

Если пользователь выбрал другую дату, то срабатывает событие, но в переменную ничего не сохраняется. Как сохранить данные в переменную?

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что ничего не сохранилось в переменную?  небось **ЗА** пределами функции в консоль пытаетесь что-то вывести?

Comment: я пытаюсь записать в переменную значение, которое получилось в функции и вызвать ее в другом месте (переменную). Объявила я ее вне функции, но перезапись значений не идет

Comment: Давайте я повторю вопрос: **Как вы проверяете, что ничего не сохранилось в переменную?**  . Где это **другое место** ?

Comment: console.log(target), за пределами функции

Comment: А теперь вопрос: почему там должно оказаться значение, если функция консоли вызывается **до** срабатывания хоть какого-либо события?  Функция ждёт срабатывания, может часами ждать....а вывод в консоль срабывает сразу же после строчки с кодом выше...........Напишите вывод в консоль внутрь функции и увидите что всё записывается